# How to restart sync process when press home button and agin tap application icon on Springboard?

Tags: iphone, ios4, object

i am developing server - client application. Data sync fro server and stored into local device and display.
  Problem is when during the sync time i tap home button and again tap on application icon on springboard. now my application getting **crashed**. how continue last sync process when i tapped application icon on spring board.(when we press home button all process will stopped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

You should use above methods of UIApplicationDelegate. It will be called when your application  changes its state. Store the necessary information at that time `applicationWillResignActive` and resume the operations in `applicationDidBecomeActive` when application becomes active.